# Tesseract unable to recognize simple text

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Im running tesseract on small images of instruments on a Piping diagram. For some reason it is unable to recognize the text though it is clear in the image. The command is text = pytesseract.image_to_string('crop.png', config='--dpi 200 --psm 12') I've tried changing the dpi and psm mode but to no avail.

[image][image]

I've tried changing the dpi and psm mode but to no avail. I'm not getting anything but garbage: "~ Cs =)"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is use easyocr. Tesseract doesn't seem to have text recognition or at least not to the degree that easyocr does.